# Reloading module/file and task issue

Tags: julia

**Goal**:
To have possibility to reload a whole module and use its exported functions and types in tasks without restarting them.

**Problem**:
I have a problem with applying a new function definitions while the task, which uses those, is running. The idea is to reload a module, not to include a file again, but further in the post I show the simplified problem version.

**A simplified example**:
Let me explain the problem using one file defining only one function `f`, as follows:

```
#sample_file.jl 
f() = info("f version 01")
```

Run `f` every 10 seconds from a task:

```
julia> include("sample_file.jl")

julia> function call_f()  
    while (true)
        f()
        sleep(10)
    end
end

julia> task = @async call_f()
```

Then in a REPL every 10 seconds we see:

```
julia> INFO: f version v01
INFO: f version 01
INFO: f version 01
INFO: f version 01
```

Now try to change definition in the `sample_file.jl`, e.g.

```
#sample_file.jl 
f() = info("f version 02")
```

In the REPL:

```
julia> reload("sample_file")
julia> f()
INFO: f version 02
```

...but the infos from the task still give:

```
julia> INFO: f version 01
INFO: f version 01
INFO: f version 01
INFO: f version 01
INFO: f version 01
...
```

**Question:**

Do you have any idea to deal with that?

Answer (score 2):

In your simplified example, this is https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/265. The function `call_f` gets compiled with the original definition of `f`, and does currently not get recompiled when `f` is changed.

In general, I think that you need to consider what you want to happen when `f` is changed. Do you want `call_f` to be recompiled? The simple solution, which doesn't need to recompile `call_f`, is to store the current function `f` in a non-const variable (`f` becomes const when you define your function). Then the jit compiler will know that the function can change and will generate an indirect call.

Comment: The assignment to a variable works for the simplified example. Now, I'll try to use it in version with modules.

Comment: Unfortunately the same approach does not play its role for modules. 

#= module file=#
module sample2_module
  export f
  f() = info("f version v001") 
end
#= main code =#
using sample2_module
  function call_f()  
 vf = sample2_module.f #vf = f does not work also!
 while (true)
  vf()
  sleep(10)
 end
  end
  task = @async call_f()
#= end of code =#

Do you have any experence with modules and the problem you pointed out?

Answer (score 0):

The core of your problem as you describe it is to [share data](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/parallel-computing/#data-movement) in parallel computing, which is always a reason to seat down and ponder about the options available, restrictions, etc.

You *can* just call [`@everywhere`](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/parallel/#Base.@everywhere) which runs a command on all processes, but I'd say this is a bad idea because you will probably bump into another data sharing/synchronization issue.

My best bet, considering the short description, would be to use a "get an update on global state" approach:

```
# main process
# ...
# 
  if should_update
    current_state.updateSomeParameter(newValue)
  end
# state is always `spawn`ed
@spawn current_state
# continue doing main process stuff

# on remote process
while do_stuff
  # do stuff
  fetch(current_state)
  updateSelfTo(current_state)
  #continue doing my remote stuff
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention and time. The problem relates to coroutines (multitasking in a single thread), not to the different threads/processes.

Comment: Even so, you _still_ need to share global state among different processes/threads/executors, which is never that simple. In your particular case, you can make the coroutines/tasks/threads aware of the changes on your .jl file by `spawn`ing and `fetch`ing. Then again, changing a .jl file might not be the best way of sharing data/state

Comment: Yes, I'm doing it by sharing a state object. As to your proposition, I'm not so sure whether a sharing object should hold all functions and types that have changed. At first I would like to know why the task does not react at all to any reload (neither from outside nor inside its scope). Any idea?